# maven filtering doesn't work for test goal

Tags: maven, filtering

I have dedicated properties files for normal run and integration tests. They are in respectivelly src/main/resources and src/test/resources. In my POM I have the following:

```
...
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
<filters>
  <filter>src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
  <filter>src/test/resources/application.properties</filter>
</filters>
...
```

When running "mvn package" I get my proprties file filtered in the target/classes directory. But when I run "mvn test" the properties file in the src/test/resources is copied in the target/test-classes one, but not filtered.

What am I missing here ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: the two files you put into <filter> are the ones you want to filter? or the ones that contain your filter values? because they should be the files that contain the filter values. usually these files with the key=values for filtering are not part of the resources directories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm replying to my own post. Here is the solution:

```
...
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>  
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
<filters>
  <filter>src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
  <filter>src/test/resources/application.properties</filter>
</filters>
...
```

This way the application.properties in both src/main/resources and src/test/resources are filtered.

Kind regards,

Nicolas